# Animate a circle in Javascript using setInterval

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to create an animation that ends after 1 minute. Basically, the circle automatically grows bigger for 5s, then back to small for 5s - on repeat for 1 minute.

Right now, I'm able to achieve this but only when the mouse enter/leave the circle. To make the circle grow automatic, I discovered setTimeout(), but right now i dont know whats wrong with my code. I'm trying to return the value from CSS (transform) that would make the circle grow bigger, but no luck.

```js
// what happents to circle
const pulseCircle = document.querySelector('#circle');
    circle.

// the interval; repeat circle every 5 seconds for one minute
let circlePulseInterval = setInterval(pulseCircle(), 5000)
  if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    circle.classList.add('hover')
    }
})

//mouse-triggered
// circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
 // if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
 //   circle.classList.add('hover')
//  }
// })

// circle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
 // if (circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
 //   circle.classList.remove('hover')
//  }
// })
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
    'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: slateblue;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 5s;
}

.hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">Hover</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n3xyufLp/

```
    // what happents to circle
const pulseCircle = document.querySelector('#circle');
    circle.


// the interval; repeat circle every 5 seconds for one minute

let circlePulseInterval = setInterval(pulseCircle(), 5000)
  if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    circle.classList.add('hover')
    My work-in-progress code: }
})
```

Comment: `pulseCircle` is a var, not a function. and your setInterval() is badly written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected example, see below. Mostly your function wasn't well formated.

```js
// what happents to circle
const pulseCircle = document.querySelector('#circle');

// the interval; repeat circle every 5 seconds for one minute

let circlePulseInterval = setInterval( () => {
   if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    circle.classList.add('hover')
 }
}, 5000)

//mouse-triggered

circle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  if (!circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    circle.classList.add('hover')
 }
})

circle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  if (circle.classList.contains('hover')) {
    circle.classList.remove('hover')
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande',
    'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: slateblue;
  border-radius: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1) 5s;
}

.hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">Hover</div>
```

Comment: thank you! for the setInterval function, ideally the circle would grow for 5s, and after that it shrinks back to original for 5s altogether for one minute. Is there a way to do this within without using the mouse-triggered code?

Comment: Yes of course. With just css. But you misss the goal of stackoverflow. This is not about questions, this is about problems. All the answers are already somewhere. This require practice. This should be easy to find. Good luck!